# Define custom path for control events

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I've been working a lot with WPF, and after awhile the `MainWindow` class becomes cluttered and unorganized. Is there a way to store all of the control events in a custom class like below? Inheriting doesn't work and i'm guessing its because it has no instance of the new class to go off of.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class ControlEvents : MainWindow //Custom class
    {
        private void Abutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look for MVVM approach where you store Event Controllers as ICommand and put them anywhere you want

Comment: as @kurakura88 said, MVVM is what your looking for. Your not taking any advantage of using WPF. Your using WPF as Windows Forms. I understand is hard to move an application to WPF, but i think you will not regret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to store all of the control events in a custom class like below?

No, the event handlers themselves *must* be defined in the code-behind of the same view class where the element is defined and the handler is hooked up.

You could move the code *inside* the event handlers to another class though:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private YourClass _handler = new YourObject();
    public class ControlEvents : MainWindow //Custom class
    {
        private void Abutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _handler.HandleButtonClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But you should look into MVVM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx. There is a reason why this is *the* recommended design pattern for developing XAML based UI applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use mvvm:

You can create user control for area of controls and load this user control in your main window.

Also - you can take your code of "do stuff" to another class and call it from the event function.
for example:

functions.cs

```
dostuff1()
{ 
  ...
}

dostuff2()
{ 
  ...
}
```

your usercontrol/mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
    functions f = new functions();
    private void Abutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        f.dostuff1();
    }
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can move all the events to [Partial class](https://www.dotnetperls.com/partial) in separated file.
 call the file MainWindowEvents.cs or something. (to remember what is it)